# Question about meaning of " swept out to" in the context

Tags: word-meaning

What does it mean when someone says ** be swept out to somewhere**

Military divers who attempted to search the ship were swept out to sea.

The sentence was caption for the picture below.

http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/74289000/jpg/_74289457_021941772-1.jpg

Answer (score 1):

To sweep means to broom, that is to remove different things using a broom.

In this case the action of waves and wind is similar to the action of a broom.

Comment: More or less, yes. Using "sweep" in this way is only idiomatic in most English dialects if (1) applied to weather (usually wind, waves, or currents) and (2) followed by a preposition ("swept out to sea," "swept away by the wind").

Comment: I’ve got it. Much obliged!